# Segfault for invalid long option

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, getopt, getopt-long

I have the following code:

```
struct option longopts[] =
  {
    {"version", no_argument, 0, 'v'}
  };

if (argc > 1)
  {
    int c;
    int longindex;
    while ((c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "v", longopts, &longindex)) != -1)
      {
        switch (c)
          {
          case 'v':
            puts (VERSION_INFO);
            exit (0);

          case '?':
            exit (1);
          }
      }
  }
```

Why is it with an argument of `--versio` (intentionally misspelled) would cause a segfault but `-a` (which is also an invalid option) just prints an "invalid option" message to the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to terminate the `longopts` array with an entry that is all zeros, otherwise `getopt_long` doesn't know when it ends.  Your code is crashing because `getopt_long` is just iterating through random memory at that point because it has fallen off the end of `longopts`.

```
struct option longopts[] =
  {
    {"version", no_argument, NULL, 'v'},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
  };
```